Can I run a 3/4in yellow poly gas line through a 1-1/2in yellow poly gas line like a sleeve?
I had a gas outdoor firepit on my old paver patio. When removing the paver patio for stamped concrete the crew cut the gas line. I was provided with the 1-1/2 in poly gas line to run for the new pit in short notice before being poured over. now there is a 1.5in poly pipe from the outside of the patio to the 36" hole meant for the new pit. It is approximately 10' in length of a run under the concrete from edge of concrete to the hole where the fire pit is to go.
Am I better off running the 1-1/2 in line all the way to the meter and getting new fittings and reducing at the actual fire ring, or can I run a new 3/4in poly line through the 1-1/2in poly like a sleeve before coming out of the ground to steel.
I was told the 1.5in poly would provide more volume for a better effect from the firepit but that seems overkill from everything I've read for a 30-36in ring at a estimate of 200k-300k btu. Also finding that 1.5in poly fittings are much harder to find and triple the price.

Gas line installed in conduit is a thing.   what you need to figure out is does the pipe you have meet all the requirements to be used as a conduit?
